# Giving three letters in autocompletetextview that a word can contain and add them in a listview

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

Here i have a code for autocompletetextview. With help of this code i can get all the words that start with first letter that a user type in textfield. But i dont know how to customize this code so the user have to give 3 letters of any word that **Contain** those letters and it should give me the result and i also want to add that word that a user choose to a listview.

```
public class tweede extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String[] producten = new String[] { "Yoghurt",
        "Cream", "Cacao", "Cola", "Yummy", "Chocolate"  };
AutoCompleteTextView ACTV;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tweede);
    ACTV=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView2);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, producten);
    ACTV.setAdapter(adapter);
    ACTV.setThreshold(1);

}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps something like: String three; for (String s : producten) { three = s.subString(0, 3); if (userText.contains(three) { // Add to listView by injecting using static method to static holder, or if its part of the listview data, manipulating that through a static handler maybe and updating the list, etc etc blah blah... } }

Answer (score 0):

you can customize up to two letter. You can check this solution.

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.(here use your layout name),R.id.(autoCompleteTextViewId), producten);

as an example....

ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_main,R.id.autoCmp,producten);